# Codename One: Can't install iOs App anymore

Tags: codenameone

I made some fixes for my App and wanted to try it out today on my iPhone and now I can't install it on the device anymore. I'm getting the error "Unable to Download App" on the phone.

I haven't changed anything on my Apple Developer Account and yesterday everything was working fine. Is this a known bug and does anybody know how to fix this? My iPhone is of course registered and I also did the "iOS Certificate Wizard" and built it again but it didn't work either.

Edit: So I was able to install the app after doing the complete Certificate Wizard again with also overwriting everything (which I had not done before), but now I made another build and I can't install it again! Do I really have to do the Wizard thing every time I send a build now?

Comment: No you don't need to run the wizard every time, is someone else using the same Apple account? Do you have more than one app? If so you must use the same certificates but two different provisionings

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to install a distribution build on top of a development build, or vice-versa? If so, uninstall the existing app first.